# Chrome Extension - waiting until a page reloads to continue script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension to automate some work of mine.
Currently it enters a value into a search, then clicks the search button.

I want to have it click another button when it gets to the next page (once loaded). But the time it takes to get to the new page varies so I can't use setTimeout (page load will take anywhere from 3 seconds to 3 minutes, totally random based on what I enter in the search).

```
$('#searchBox').val(Arr[i]); //Where Arr is a series of search values
$('#searchSubmit').click();
//Wait until new page is up, then continue
$('#anotherButton').click();
//etc
```

So I'm stumped. How on earth do I tell the script to wait until the new page has loaded? In the console network tab I can see it is pending until executed. Is there a way I can hook into this to wait? Or is there are mutationobserver of some sort I can use to detect the new page load?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this failure was a logical one. Because it's javascript and thus front end facing and I didn't want to interfere with multiple tabs, I had to accept I couldn't listen for page reload (as script went with the reload, obviously). I simply told the script to listen for the main url. if it found the main url it was likely at the first instance of the script, so I passed a 0 as a parameter of my function. If it wasn't on the main page, I passed a 1, triggering a different line of logic. In the end I used length counts on the page to indicate page differences, to then pass through different parameters based on this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. Use `tabs` API in background page to check when page has loaded. Once done, send a message to that tab and continue the script.
2. The simple one I used recently:

   ```
   window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      $('#anotherButton').click();
   });
   ```

Should work.

Comment: I'm running it as a content script. It's a .js file that runs on a set website. The latter doesn't seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: When you click search, page reloads or just loads the content via AJAX etc?

Comment: Navigates to new page

Answer (score 0):

Not easy to help you without any code.  But in my own extensions, each time a page is loaded or reloaded, my *content* script is called. Then I simply check the value of (or part of) the `location.href` to know what was going on and branch accordingly.

Comment: You mean your content script.

Answer (score 0):

I made a helper function which checks the loading state of current tab every 500ms:

```js
function waitLoad(callback) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, (tabs) => {
        let timer = setInterval(() => {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {
                code: `eval("document.readyState")`,
            }, (data) => {
                if (data[0]==="complete"){
                    callback()
                    clearInterval(timer)
                }
            })
        }, 500)
    })
}
```